# How to make a JavaScript function that usually returns true, but returns false randomly, once every 50 times on average?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a function that returns `true` most of the time when it's called but that will return `false` occasionally?

By occasionally I mean, at 1000 calls, it'll have an average of one `false` every 50 calls.

Comment: You can do it with Math.random: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty easy, use `Math.random` to get a number between 0 and 1, and compare it to `0.02` or the rate of true/false you are looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

So, basically:

```
var randomizer = function () {
    return Math.random() > 0.02;
};
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make it more beautiful, you can pack this function in an object, and set there the ratio of true/false.

```
var randomizer = {
    _ratio: 0.02,  // default ratio
    setRatio: function (falses, total) {
        this._ratio = falses / total;
    },
    getResult: function () {
        return Math.random() > this._ratio;
    }
};
```

and then

```
randomizer.getResult(); 
randomizer.setRatio(60, 1000); // 60 out of 10000
```

Comment: To make things a bit more configurable: `var randomizer = function(n, total){ return Math.random() > (n/total); }; // randomizer(50, 1000)`, or even `var createRandomizer(n, total){ return function() { return Math.random() > (n/total); }; }; // var randomizer = createRandomizer(50, 1000); randomizer();`

Comment: Yeah, well, in my case I would create an object with configurable rate.

Comment: Thanks for the non-commented downvote. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function mostlyFalse() {
    return Math.random() <= 0.05;    
}
```

jsfiddle randomly showing mostly 'true's, but with the occasional 'false': http://jsfiddle.net/t8E6t/1/

Comment: That function should be called `mostlyFalse` =)

Answer (score 1):

How about

Odds: 50/1000  = 1/20

```
//Get random number from 1 to 20, if equals 20 return false
if (Math.floor((Math.random()*20)+1) == 20)
{
  return false;
}
else{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You could just `return Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 20) + 1 ) == 20;`

Answer (score 1):

With `Math.random`, you can achieve what you want :

```
function suchRandom(chanceInPercent){
    return Math.random() > chanceInPercent/100;
}

console.log(suchRandom(2)); //because 1000/50 = 20 true / 1000 calls = 2%
```

Around 20 : http://jsfiddle.net/Ru7qY/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo () { return Math.random() > 0.02; }

// 1 / 50 == 0.02, so if it's less than 0.02 return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a random number each time the function runs, between 1 and 50:

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
```

Then, if the number equals 50, for example, return false.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the most concise, simple answer is this one-liner function

```
// A function that has a 50% chance of returning true by default
function chance( c = 0.5 ){
    return Math.random() < c;
}
```

Use it like so

```
// Block has a 60% chance of being executed.
if( chance( .6 ) ){
    //Do stuff
}

// Or, to solve your problem specifically
var c = chance( 49 / 50 );
```

Answer (score -1):

counter.... :D

```
var c = 0;
function f()
{
    return ++c % 50 == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Pretty interesting concept of "random" xD

Comment: @ikaros45 yes, i know what `Math.random` is, i had just tried to get different answer, when i had posted this, there were some posts with `Math.random` solution ;)

Comment: It is not about `Math.random` but the concept of random. Your function is not random, but predictable.

Comment: @ikaros45 yes, its predictable

Comment: Yup. I mean, it does in fact give a 2% of `false`s, but it is not exactly what he wanted ;). By the way, the ternary is not necessary, you could just use `return ++c % 50 != 0;`

Comment: @ikaros45, you right again about `return ++c % 50 != 0;`, NEXT ... :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48700/discussion-between-am1r-5h-and-ikaros45)